# What does the phrase "select object into device context" mean?

Tags: visual-c++, gdi

I'm having trouble understanding the [SelectObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-selectobject) function because I don't know what "select into" means in the explanation "The SelectObject function selects an object into the specified device context (DC).".

Normally when you select something, you select one object e.g. a block of text you want to copy, but how can you select something into something else, and what does that mean?

```
HGDIOBJ SelectObject(
  HDC     hdc,
  HGDIOBJ h
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a link to [Setting the Pen or Brush Color](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/desktop/gdi/setting-the-pen-or-brush-color) at the bottom of the page you linked. It can explain better. `SelectObject` lets you to configure GDI environment, e.g. pen or brash, so you can draw complex scene w/o repeatedly specifying them in each GDI call.

Comment: I think I understand now, what it really means is e.g. select pen to use on paper (but instead of paper you have the DC). In normal language you don't say "select pen into paper". That's what got me confused LOL.

Answer (score 0):

GDI always provides a "current" object of each type in a DC (pen, brush, text color, etc.), which is used when an operation runs, which refers to it (e.g. DrawText refers to a current font, test color, etc.). A freshly created DC starts with default objects which you can change by "selecting" another one.